# Call to unmanaged dll kills process without raising exception

Tags: c#, interop, unmanaged

I have a WPF C# application targeting version 4.5 of the .Net framework. My application is calling an un-managed DLL, all but one method is working fine. When I call the problem method my process exits without raising any exceptions, the exit code is: `1073741855 (0x4000001f)`

I've read about the [`<legacyCorruptedStateExceptionsPolicy>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd638517(v=vs.110).aspx) element and have added it to my app.config file. I've turned on ALL exceptions in the Exception Settings dialog (I'm using VS2015, BTW). At this point I've run out of techniques to determine what is causing the process to exit.

Update: I happened to try turning on Enable native code debugging in the project settings and now receive the following exception:

> Exception thrown at 0x77CBED0B (ntdll.dll) in
>   SK.UnmanagedDLLExceptionTest.exe: 0xC0000374: A heap has been
>   corrupted (parameters: 0x77CF4270).

Given the above information, do any of you know any other techniques that can be used to bring additional details to the surface?

If you are interested (and willing) I have created a dead-simple console application that exhibits the problem, [download here](http://spireon.d.pr/AJ2J/1hVrEmpm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By turning on "Enable native code debugging" in the Project Settings I was able to have the following exception thrown up:

> Exception thrown at 0x77CBED0B (ntdll.dll) in
>   SK.UnmanagedDLLExceptionTest.exe: 0xC0000374: A heap has been
>   corrupted (parameters: 0x77CF4270)

And while that certainly isn't good news, it DOES provide more details and steer me in the direction of a misbehaving dll.

Comment: I spent *hours* trying to catch a subtle TypeLoadException that was being swallowed by WCF. This allowed me to pinpoint the error. Lifesaver.

Answer (score 1):

The catch legacy flag doesn't help if you don't actually catch anything.

The error seems to decode to DLL not found.

That's a 32 bit DLL and you compiled as Any CPU. If you have x64 (and you probably do), this is the problem. Compile specifically as x86.

If you put the catch in there, it still won't help as bindings are compiled at method entry (before the try is reached).

Comment: Sounded promising. I made the change you suggested but am experiencing the same results. While in the Project settings page I noticed the "Enable native code debugging" option and tried it, this resulted in the following exception:
Exception thrown at 0x77CBED0B (ntdll.dll) in SK.UnmanagedDLLExceptionTest.exe: 0xC0000374: A heap has been corrupted (parameters: 0x77CF4270).

Comment: You're in serious trouble then. The DLL corrupted the process heap or something.

Comment: I'm hosed. :) Turns out the breakthrough for me was to turn on the Enable native code debugging option. Thanks for your assistance though, I appreciate it